# Set up secure DNS (over TLS or HTTPS) on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, security, dns

**How do I set up Secure DNS (eg over TLS or HTTPS) on 16.04?**

I would prefer to use functionality built into 16.04 or apps available on the 16.04 repository. I plan to use either the Google Public DNS (eg 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) or Cloudflare (1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1) or some combination of the two.

From a web search, the commonly recommended way is to use [stubby on 18.04](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-stubby-dns-over-tls) for DNS over TLS, but stubby does not seem to be available on the 16.04 repository.

Current options for DNS over HTTP seems to be [cloudflared by Cloudfare](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/dns-over-https/cloudflared-proxy/) and [doh-proxy by Facebook](https://facebookexperimental.github.io/doh-proxy/), neither of which seem to be available on the 16.04 repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu there is [the **dnss** package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/dnss) ([official site](https://blitiri.com.ar/git/r/dnss/b/master/t/f=README.md.html))

From [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dnss.1.html):

> dnss is a daemon that can encapsulate DNS over HTTPS.
>
> It can act as a DNS-to-HTTPS proxy, using https://dns.google.com as a
>   server or anything implementing the same API.
>
> It can also act as an HTTPS-to-DNS proxy, implementing the same HTTP
>   API; you can use this instead of https://dns.google.com if you want
>   more control over the servers and the final DNS server used (for
>   example if you are in an isolated environment, such as a test lab or a
>   private network).
>
> In the default mode of operation, it listens for DNS requests on port
>   53, and will query an HTTPS server (https://dns.google.com by default)
>   to resolve them.

Comment: Thanks for the response. There is very little in terms of a users guide on dnss. Have you used it yourself?

Comment: I used it a couple of years ago. Now I have a microtik rounter that does everything relative to my dns.

Answer (score 1):

On Firefox, [you can enable this](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/encryption/dns-over-https/encrypted-dns-browsers/#mozilla-firefox) by navigating to the browser's *Settings* → *Network Settings* and checking *Enable DNS over HTTPS* as shown in the screenshot:

[image: Firefox settings]

Chrome/Chromium/Brave has [a similar setting](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/encryption/dns-over-https/encrypted-dns-browsers/#google-chrome), which you can enable by navigating to the browser's *Settings* → *Privacy and security* → *Advanced* → *Use secure DNS*.